# Equivalent of Objective-C's setTimeZone in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need to do some date-to-string conversions in a SQL query (SQL Server 2012).  I'm familiar with `CONVERT(DATETIME,myString,127)` function, but this will give me a string with a timezone appended at the end.  I don't want to show any timezone information in the string, but I want the time that gets shown expressed in UTC.

For example, in Objective-C I could do:

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSString *myString = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

With this code, I will get a string that does not show a timezone, but the time expressed will be in UTC.  Is there a way to get this behavior in a SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some ways to do something similar to what wallyk suggested in his answer, but unfortunately it is much more complicated with SQL Server.  For me, it ended up being easier to just keep the result of the query as a `DateTime`, and then convert to a string later in the code that is calling the query.  I suspect others will find it easier this way as well, since a lot of programming frameworks seem have more extensive support for type conversions than SQL does.

I'll mark this as the answer for now, even though it doesn't actually answer the question as stated.  If someone posts a simple, elegant way to do the conversion right in the query itself, I'll accept that instead.

Answer (score 0):

When the server connection is established, you can set your per-client timezone to [whatever you want](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone).

```
set time_zone = 'US/Pacific'
```

If you frequently use different timezones, there is the [`convert_tz()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
        -> '2004-01-01 13:00:00'
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','+00:00','+10:00');
        -> '2004-01-01 22:00:00'
```

---

(Ooops!  Just noticed the sql-server tag.   Well, here is the answer for MySQL.)

Comment: I did some digging, and unfortunately it turns out that doing it this way is not as simple in SQL Server.  Thanks anyway though.